# Matrix Multi-Upload does not populate Matrix rows

Tags: matrix, file-manager

Just installed Matrix & Matrix Multi-Upload but cannot get it to work on my EE system.

Installed EE Version: 2.5.2

The fields have been created as instructed but the images dont seem to populate the rows of the Matrix field once uploaded.

Need some help... thanks Corey

[image]

Comment: What versions of Matrix Multi-Upload and Matrix are you running?

Comment: I'll find out but they were just downloaded today...

Comment: Matrix 2.5.1 and Multi-Upload is 0.9.3?